# I have changes server and TinyMCE is adding www, before everything that is uploaded

Tags: apache, upload, tinymce

On previous hosting it was working great, but on my new hosting the files that are uploaded have www before them when added via TinyMCE.

e.g.

```
/www/uploads/pages/file/my-uploaded-file.png
```

instead of the correct:

```
/uploads/pages/file/my-uploaded-file.png
```

I guess it's something with incorrect server settings.

Could somebody help me what is configured wrong on the server, because on my localhost and on previous server it was working as expected ;(

**EDIT:**
the result link looks like:

```
http://mywebsite.com/www/uploads/pages/file/my-uploaded-file.png
```

and I need to have:

```
http://mywebsite.com/uploads/pages/file/my-uploaded-file.png
```